# Entity Framework Core multiple table relationship

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to create relationship where parent has many children and also includes the oldest child. How to correctly configure that relationship and how to insert the data into the tables?

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   
   public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Plural of "child" is "children" - not "childs"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against trying to store it as a separate property. Instead, calculate it from existing data with a get-only property something like:

```
public Child OldestChild => Childs.OrderByDescending(c => c.Age).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you are concerned about the cost of repeated access, you can look into wrapping the access logic using the Lazy<> class or some other caching methods.  If you do, be aware that changes to the Childs collection would then not be reflected in the cached OldestChild result.

FOLLOW-UP: The above is still incomplete as it doesn't resolve cases of children of the same age - close birthdates, twins, adoptees, etc.  That also raises the question: Why are are you modeling age (which changes over time vs Birthdate, which is fixed.